# add a new font in react project

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am starting a new website in React and I need to use a font from Google called FredokaOne.

I have used the command:

```
npm install --save typeface-fredoka-one
```

Everything went well but I can't figure-out how to use it. 
I tried this :

```
font-family: FredokaOne;
font-size: 40px;
```

But it still using the default font. Is there a way to checkout the proper font to use ?
or any missing params.

Thanks
Regards

Comment: I assume you have `require('typeface-fredoka-one')` in your entry file?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `@import` inside `index.css` file of react project.

#### Index.css

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fredoka+One&display=swap');

*{
   font-family: 'Fredoka One', cursive;
}
```